# RDF namespace that can describe SPARQL queries?

Tags: namespaces, rdf

Assuming I have some RDF graph, here a shape graph:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix shex: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shex#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://XYZ> a shex:Shape ;
 ...
```

and a SPARQL query that I want to associate with the root node shown above. Is there a namespace that lets me make statements to the effect that "SELECT ABC" is the `xsd:string` of a SPARQL query that is associated with XYZ? How can this meta-statement be expressed if I use `skos:related` for the association?

Explanation, what do I mean with association? ShEx objects (shapes) describe a model that a set of graphs should conform to. This set can be defined by a SPARQL query, so in order not to have to test all possible graphs in a database we want to associate a query with a shape.

Comment: There is [SPIN](https://www.w3.org/Submission/2011/SUBM-spin-sparql-20110222/), basically a 1:1 correspondence to the SPARQL syntax tree. But I am not sure what do you mean by associating a SPARQL query with the root node.

Comment: @IllidanS4supportsMonica this is already very helpful. Apparently SPIN can also hold a textual version of the query so I can use `sp:Query` to hold the query without the need to transform it. As I said in the updated question the meta-property `skos:related` can be used to express the association with the shape.

Comment: I see; I will turn it into an answer then.

Comment: If there is a better property or way to associate the two concepts please go ahead and add that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For representing SPARQL expressions and queries, there is [SPIN](https://www.w3.org/Submission/2011/SUBM-spin-sparql-20110222/), with structures equivalent to the SPARQL syntax tree. Queries can have a textual form attached, so you don't have to convert them:

```
_:query a sp:Query ;
  sp:text "SELECT ABC" .
```

For the association, I think `skos:related` might be too broad, but I don't know ShEx to say for sure. If a shape basically corresponds to a query (from some point of view), `skos:closeMatch` could also be an option.

SPIN also allows linking rules or constraints to classes, via `spin:rule` or `spin:constraint`, respectively, which might be of use as well.